# Skipping calculation of somes primes when asking lot of primes

Tags: ada

I just started to learn some ada code and would create my very own primes calculator.
To procress, I use one of most known method, which is :
"each primes is a result of 6 * x -+ 1 "

So this is my code :

```
with Ada.Text_IO, Ada.Integer_Text_IO ;
use Ada.Text_IO, Ada.Integer_Text_IO ;

procedure main is

   count_prime : Integer := 0 ;
   counter : Integer := 1 ;
   wanted : Integer ;
   iteration : Integer := 0 ;
   testing : Integer := 0 ;
   is_prime : Boolean ;

   answer : Character ;
begin
   loop
      Put("Prime calculator") ;
      New_line(2) ;
      Put("Put 'p' to process") ;
      New_Line(1);
      Put("Put 'q' to quit") ;
      New_Line(2) ;
      Put(">> ") ;

      Get(answer) ;
      if answer = 'p' then
         Put("Enter wanted primes :");
         Get(wanted) ;
         Skip_line ;

         if wanted > 0 then
            Put("2");
            New_Line(1);
            if wanted > 1 then
               Put("3");
               New_Line(1);
            end if ;

            if wanted > 2 then
               count_prime := 2;
               loop
                  if counter = 1 then
                     counter := 0 ;
                     iteration := iteration + 1 ;
                     testing := ( 6 * iteration ) - 1 ;
                  else
                     counter := 1 ;
                     testing := ( 6 * iteration ) + 1 ;
                  end if ;

                  is_prime := True ;

                  for i in 2..(testing-1) loop

                     if (testing rem i = 0) then
                        is_prime := False ;
                     end if ;

                  end loop;

                  if is_prime = True then
                     Put(testing);
                     New_Line(1);
                     count_prime := count_prime + 1 ;
                  end if ;

                  exit when count_prime = wanted;
               end loop ;
            end if;

            Put("Ended") ;

         else
            Put("It's can't be a negative number");
         end if ;

      end if ;

      New_Line(3);
      exit when answer = 'q' ;
   end loop ;
end main ;
```

I really know this is a basic, I mean ouh, extremely basic program. But I would just solve the problem I've asked :

with 'p' and 2 :

```
2
3
```

with 'p' and '7'

```
2
3
          5
          7
         11
         13
         17
```

with 'p' and 1200

```
2
3
         19
         23
         29
         31
         37
         41
....
```

Where are gone all primes between 3 and 19 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You keep running the calculation in a cycle, but do not reset it's initial state. The `loop` that performs the calculation continues using values of `iteration`, `counter` and a few other variables from the previous run.

Either decompose the loop into a separate procedure, or at least surround it with `declare` block, e.g.:

```
declare
  count_prime : Integer := 2;
  counter : Integer := 1;
  iteration : Integer := 0;
  testing : Integer := 0;
  is_prime : Boolean;
begin
  loop
    …
    end loop;
  end;
```

However, I'd strongly recommend decomposing into a separate `procedure`.

Comment: I put a reset for variable but when I enter 4, my program run infinitely

Answer (score 0):

```
        if wanted > 2 then
           count_prime := 2;
```

-- you probably want to reset `iteration` here...

```
           iteration := 0;
           loop
              if counter = 1 then
```